# Python warn prints message and call on Windows cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I'm having a problem with the display of warning messages in Python 2.7.  Here's a minimum working example:

```
from warnings import warn

# It is a warning after all...
warn("Goodbye cruel world")
```

If I run this from the Windows command prompt, then I get the warning message but also the source code, e.g.

```
test.py:3: UserWarning: Goodbye cruel world
  warn("Goodbye cruel world")
```

What's going on here?  How can I get it to only display the first line of this output?

Comment: You can't, that's how the `warnings`  module work.

Comment: Rhetorical question, but why on earth would you want that?  Thanks for clarifying; this behaviour wasn't clear in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to log something, [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) is more appropriate:

```
import logging

# logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logging.warn("Goodbye cruel world")
```